# How to read/write ldif file through a java program?

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

I chose to write a java program to take back up of my LDAP entries in LDIF file and also would like to rollback the modifications using the back up LDIF files, if needed.

Please provide references and also other better approaches.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using OpenLDAP there is the `slapcat` utility, and I can't imagine that the other vendors don't provide similar utilities. No need to write any code at all.

Comment: We are using Sun Directory Server. Researching on some tools.